# no such table: hadis (code 1)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I have a problem to select from alist of data from database. I have created my table using SQLite Browser and I imported the database into the studio. I want to read the data from the database. Here is the initialization of the database :

```
public static String DB_PATH            = "data/data/com.psm.app.hadis40_07/databases/";
public static String DB_NAME            = "hadis40_db";
public static String TABLE_LOCATION     = "hadis";
```

The logcat prompt :

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: hadis (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  hadis_id,no_hadis,tajuk_hadis,hadis,terjemahan,tajuk_audio_hadis,audio_hadis,pengajaran_hadis,sebab_wurud_hadis FROM hadis
```

Here is the method that I have called the database :

```
 public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getHadisList() {
    //Open connection to read only
    //SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelperHadis.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery =  "SELECT  " +
            Hadis.KEY_hadisID + "," +
            Hadis.KEY_noHadis + "," +
            Hadis.KEY_tajukHadis + "," +
            Hadis.KEY_hadis + "," +
            Hadis.KEY_terjemahan + "," +
            Hadis.KEY_tajukAudio + "," +
            Hadis.KEY_audioHadis + "," +
            Hadis.KEY_pengajaranHadis + "," +
            Hadis.KEY_sebabWurud +
            " FROM " + TABLE_LOCATION;

    SQLiteDatabase  db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase( DB_PATH + DB_NAME , null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    //Student student = new Student();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> hadisList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> hadis = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hadis.put("id", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Hadis.KEY_hadisID)));
            hadis.put("name", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Hadis.KEY_noHadis)));
            hadisList.add(hadis);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return hadisList;

}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: are you executing this after creating your table?

Comment: yup... I have created my table... I created my table using SQLlite Browser and I imported the db into the studio

Comment: Is there a table called *hadis* in the database???, maybe you forget to initialize it

Comment: Double check the table name, and database data

Comment: If one of the column is NULL, is it cause the calling data error? I have allowed NULL to that column

Comment: no NULL won't create problem

Comment: It have solved, when I double check and pull the database from device, the table is absolutely not in the database. I thought when import the databse into studio, it will automatically insert into device. Hence, I push the database into the device. The problem have solved. Thanks